# Change Height of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to make a `UITableViewCell` bigger. How can I do this, I have tried adjusting its frame but nothing happens. What can I do?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to implement the

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method in your [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 18):

You can do like this..

```
//Change the Height of the Cell [Default is 44]:
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
   if (indexPath.row == 1) {
     return 90;
   }
  }
  return 44;
}
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: actually i am doing something similar i make it bigger compared to the text labels length

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 steps to change height of a table cell **without** any additional code:

1. Select your `Table View` from your Storyboard. In the `Size Inspector` change `Row Height`.
2. Select your `Table View Cell` and while it's selected in the `Size Inspector` change the `Row Height`.

Note that you *MUST* set **BOTH** of Table View's `Row Height` attribute and Table View Cell's `Row Height` attribute.

If you just set one of them, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/156210) to be the most informative and most up-to-date to change the height of a table view cell.

TL;DR

1. Take extra care when making your Auto Layout constraints
2. Enable row height estimation on your table view in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; // set to whatever your "average" cell height is

Comment: This is a late answer to an old question.  If you feel that this question is a duplicate, it should be flagged as such.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code for changing the height of different tableview

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == tableView1) 
    {
        return 55;
    }
    else if(tableView == tableView2)
    {
        return 75;
    }
}
```

This may help you.