# single cell height in UITableView Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Sorry i know this question has been asked before but i can't seem to get it to work, i would like to change the height of the first cell in my UITableView and keep the rest as default 44.  I have implemented the below code (tried various others) and my application builds but the cell height does not change. Any help on this would be great.

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 150;
    }
    else {
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Comment: try - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Height of a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543846/change-height-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did this code work out for you?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     if (indexPath.row == 0) 
          return 150;
      else
          return 44;
}
```

Comment: it didn't do anything to the cell.. I'm not sure if in storyboard maybe there is a setting that fixes the height?

Comment: Sorted, i didn't need 'estimated' in front of height.

Comment: @burrGGG i've explained the difference between the 2 in my answer

Comment: @burrGGG Adding the documentation comments for 'estimated' thing,

// Use the estimatedHeight methods to quickly calcuate guessed values which will allow for fast load times of the table.
// If these methods are implemented, the above -tableView:heightForXXX calls will be deferred until views are ready to be displayed, so more expensive logic can be placed there.

Answer (score 1):

```
estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath
```

is used to calculate the position / size of the scroll bar on the side when using autoLayout, not the cell height. You need:

```
heightForRowAtIndexPath
```